# Finding more information on grandfather born in Lemburg in 1892

Tags: poland, vital-records, ukraine, austria-hungary

I have looked on Jewish.org and gesher galicia but can still find no information on my grandfather Leopold whose 1933 UK naturalisation certificate reports him being born in Lemburg (now Lviv) on 15th November 1892 to Nathan and Minna Neuwald. He married in a Protestant church but his parents names led me to believe he may have been born into a Jewish family, hence checking these sources.

Any ideas on where else to look?